# Does a rubber sink stopper transfer kosher status?

Tags: kashrut-kosher

We rent a place with stainless steel sinks I kashered last Pesach to be fleishig but there are rubber sink stoppers all I could do was clean until they were clear of food particles. The people who used to live here weren't Jewish so I can't imagine what flavors would be in there. I have let them sit over 24 hrs after being cleaned. So I'm wondering now if I pour boiling water into the sink, and it's all sitting in there with these rubber stoppers and the stainless steel base all connected to the same boiling water, is it making the sink not kosher?

Comment: +1 Welcome to the site! thanks for sharing the question. Be aware that this site does not offer rabbinic guidance, so treat everything you read here as no more authoritative than something you heard from a friend. Have a good year.